# Objective-C - Post request + MAMP

Tags: php, objective-c, post

I know that there are already some answers about it, but I swear that I still didn't found a clear one. My question is straight: how do I send a POST request to a PHP page?

Bonus question: I'm trying to do it on a local server (MAMP). Do I need to change something to make it work?

Comment: [There's a classic answer to that very question.](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Believe me that I didn't just came up here without trying nothing. I did try a lot of ways, but all of them seems not working. That's why I asked for a CLEAR way to do it and not just a "fixing" way, because I can't be sure which is the right way to do it.

Comment: so read the article, Seva linked. than you will realize, that it is your duty, to tell us, WHAT you tried, and — if possible — WHY it failed. That something didn't work a useful information

Comment: otherwise an answer "Yes, it works in several ways." must be considered valid too.

Comment: I don't get if you are trying to flame or what else? I tried a lot of ways and they didn't work. Instead of picking one of them randomly and ask you to fix it, I came here and I asked for the best method to send a post request to a PHP page. Isn't this website made for this? If I had a code with a problem, I'd have posted it.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: Ehm? If you were referring to the snippet, I didn't just "copy-pasted" it. Come on...

Comment: I was referring to you looking at my comments in the end of the snippet and not realizing you have to DO SOMETHING MEANINGFUL in this area of the code.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: I didn't, because I had a php page who should have done all the job after that it had received the variables.

Comment: You said "it keeps saying that the variable NSData *d is unused". I gave you a -1 because of your inability to understand that the it's your job to do something about the variable d, as signified by my comment. That's basic understanding of Objective C. Also "it keeps doing nothing". If you tried to read and understand the code I gave, you'd see that the code does nothing to the HTTP output it receives and that's the point. StackOverflow is not Rent-a-Coder - we're not here to give you complete solutions. You're still expected to think for yourself, and you'll get -1's when you don't do that.

Comment: As you want. I thought this website was meant for people who were learning programming and who could make that kind of mistake. Not for frustated people who has to point out these kind of things. Have a nice day.

Comment: As I already said, you're keeping accuse me of something that I didn't do. You said that I didn't do something about the variable "d", when it was clear to me that I didn't need that. Are you happy with the "-1"? Good for you. Luckily there are a lot of programmers who are really more kind than you.

Comment: oh, there are a lot programmers like him. count me in.

Comment: "You" in English has two meanings. ;-)
By the way, it's sad that you want to put me in the pot of the people who just come here and wants all to be done from others. I did a lot of tries to resolve this thing on my own and then I get blamed because of a misunderstanding. This should be a site of helping, not hating.

Comment: people here like to help — but just if enough afford is put in asking. "I tried a lot" is not enough. If you want high quality answers, you need to provide high quality informations. for anything else you will have to expect down and close votes. and you shouldnt tell Seva, what Stackoverflow is. he has 15,500 reputation points — he knows, what it is.

Comment: Having high reputation means that you should act as that, not telling to others "shut up, I have high reputation". My answer was really straight and I preferred to ask how to do it, instead of asking to you fix something that maybe was wrong till start. That was a choice of mine. That deserved a -1? Ok. No problem. That is a right of yours. What do you want more? That I go down on my knees telling you that you're a really kind programmer? You're not for me. Maybe you're good, but not kind and polite. And this is a right of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"127.0.0.1/index.php?id=0"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:requestURL];

NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

/edit

Sorry, I just saw you're after POST, not GET, something like this should work:

[NSURLConnection with POST](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=7501837&postcount=2)

Comment: this will work if he's doing a GUI app, if he is writing command line and is not threading himself that wont work as the program will finish execution before the request finishes. In that case he should look into the NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest method.

Comment: If he's doing a command line application in Foundation, I'd expect him to instantiate a runloop in order to prevent instant termination of the application, and then terminating at a later date. This is how most Foundation based terminal applications operate since it provides the ability to create classes and respond to events in an asynchronous manner.

Comment: could you point me towards how to do that or an example (not obj-c expert here)? thats a problem i've faced in a bit of code i'm trying to share between gui and command line and i haven't seen an example that worked for me.

Comment: You'd add something like this to main.m:

 AppDelegate * delegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
 
 NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
 
 NSApplication * application = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
 [application setDelegate:delegate];
 [NSApp run];
 
 [pool drain];
 
 [delegate release];

Comment: that actually makes a ton of sense. thanks for that, that helped me out a great bit.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it. Note: this is an sync request; you can do it in async manner as well. The latter is much better style with cloud servers, but with a local one won't make much difference.

Also, I presume that you're submitting a set of form fields (emulate an HTML form), as opposed to some other data format. On the PHP side, those fields become available as the $_POST collection.

In the sample below, the fields and values are dummy. Substitute real ones.

```
NSString *URLEncode(NSString *s)
{
    return [s stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
} 

void SendPOST()
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *Req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:
        [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/path/file.php"]];
    //Plug a sensible URL here

    [Req addValue: @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
    [Req setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];

    //Let's compose the POST data out of fields and values!
    NSMutableString *POSTData = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:1000];
    [POSTData appendString: @"Param1="];
    [POSTData appendString: URLEncode(@"Value1")];
    [POSTData appendString: @"&Param2="];
    [POSTData appendString: URLEncode(@"Value2")];

    [Req setHTTPBody: [POSTData dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];      
    //Your encoding might vary 

    NSURLResponse *Resp;
    NSError *Err;
    NSData *d = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:Req
        returningResponse:&Resp error:&Err];
    if([(NSHTTPURLResponse*)Resp statusCode] != 200)
        NSLog(@"We have an error: %d", [(NSHTTPURLResponse*)Resp statusCode]);
    else
    {
        NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:d
            encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Got some data back: %@", s);
        [s release]; //Not needed if you're using ARC.
    }   
}
```

Comment: I tried this one, but like a lot of other tries, it keeps saying that the variable NSData *d is unused. I put your script inside a function called from a button, but it keeps doing nothing. It reach the end and it doesn't get into the "We have an error" statement.

As you said, yes, I have a virtual form. Could be the localhost thing that it's screwing all up?

Comment: It's an INCOMPLETE snippet. Instead of //We have an error and //process the data, you're expected to provide your own code. The variable d is unused - are YOU using it? I can't imagine what do you want to do to it. The simplest thing would be - convert it to string and dump. See my edit.

Comment: The fact is that I have a PHP script that should send to a MySQL database the variables that it receive from this script, but it doesn't do that. I'm pretty sure the PHP script works, because I tested it with a classic HTML form and it doesn't have problems.

Comment: Is the PHP emitting anything at all back? Can you see it in the client code? The debugging process is tracing every step. I, for one, don't know yet if the request is not reaching the PHP script or if the script itself is misbehaving. One way to know that is to examine script output on the client side. Try the "dump the output" version I've pasted.

Comment: I get back the whole PHP page.

Comment: You get the *sources* of the PHP page, with `<?php ... ?>` elements in it? Then PHP is not enabled in MAMP. Debug on the MAMP administration side, the POST code is working as expected. A properly working Web server with PHP enabled should never return the `<?php ... ?>` elements.

Comment: I found the problem! It was all correct, but with this kind of request I didn't get into the if(isset($_REQUEST['Submit'])) statement. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, no, I received the compiled page ;-)